# Data Extension | Can we use the format of date as "Tuesday, February 25, 2020" in the data file

Tags: marketing-cloud

I had tried by taking data type as text and also as date for "Tuesday, February 25, 2020" and the result I got is none of the records got imported. Can someone please help me out on this.

My import file looks as below,

[image]

My DE fields looks as below,

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the formatting the date column to a text date column using SQL with Convert() and DatePart()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it might be errorig out is because you don't have the correct format. here are the supported date formats

**http://help.marketingcloud.com/contentassets/07cc53e235984271b7f0d12c02e1a5d8/dateformats_bylocale.txt**

make sure when you import you have the right selection as per the date format.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The date format values available to select when importing only support numeric values, example: 1/19/2016 1:44 PM.  There is no option that allows for handling the day of the week and month formatted with their full name.

Comment: Adding to your answer. If the reason for having that date format is email personalization purposes then you can achieve it using AMPScript. The FormatDate() function https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/dateTimeFormatting.htm.